# Warning while compiling code on ios device

Tags: ios4, ipad, xcodebuild, xcode4

I am getting this warning while compiling my code on ipad.

warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib

Any Idea as what symbols it is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

XCode4 is still under NDA right? You will find an answer to this specific issue over at Apple's developer forums.

Comment: I'm getting the same error using Xcode 3.2.5. It only occurs if I build my application for the Device (iPhone 4)?

Comment: Thanks firoze. I would take a look at that

Comment: I am getting this error now too often when ever i compile my app on my ipad.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something you need to worry about.

See the thread here:
https://devforums.apple.com/thread/77896